# Can not access sqlite database file in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developping an Android apllication i wich i have an sqlite database which i want to extract the file (.db) to manage it with a manager (like sqlitemanager for example).

For that, i searched in many sites and the answer of the "how question" was the same, it consists of the following steps ( from http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/4991/copy-sqlite-db-into-android-app )  :

1) Open the Android-sdk-windows

2) then open the tools

3) then ddms open

4) Dalvik Debug Monitor is open

5) then Device -> File Explorer.

6) data/data/your_project_package/files/your_database_file.db

7) copy your_database_file.db and open sqlite manager

I have followed these steps normally but my problem is that my data folder is empty !!, it does contain any another folder, and am getting this although i installed the application on the device, so i do not know what is the problem source.

I will be gratefull for any help

Thanks.

Comment: It's likely your app isn't creating the database at all.

Answer (score 0):

### In the image below,Let if `com.android.browser` is the package name of your application then your database will be created in the db folder (not in the image ) as a sibling of lib.

[image]

---

**Note:** While working with sqlite database in android,I came to know that the created database will not show up even after the `create` statement for the tables are executed.They(the databases) are visible only in the DDMS file explorer, when some row is inserted in the table.So make sure you are performing some insertion before  you start dealing with the database.